# Schema.org - Duplicate itemtype?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I am adding Schema to a contact page I am building. The page has both a physcial address which is an office, however, the mailing address is not the same. Here is what I have done using Schema:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">   
<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
 <ul>
  <li>Office: <span itemprop="streetAddress">1234 Anywhere Street</span>
   <br/> <span itemprop="addressLocality">Denver</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion">CO</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">80000</span>
  </li>
 </ul>            
</div>
<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
 <ul>
  <li>Mailing: Post Office Box <span itemprop="postOfficeBoxNumber">5555</span>
  <br/> <span itemprop="addressLocality">Denver</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion">CO</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">80000</span>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div> 
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>Phone: <span itemprop="telephone">555-555-5555</span></li>
  <li>Fax:  <span itemprop="faxNumber">555-555-5555</span></li>
 </ul>
</div>      
</div>
```

My questions:

- Is it technically correct to have two instances of `<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">`?
- If not how do I leave the second `<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">`?

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's technically correct from syntax point of view. But unfortunately one has no chance to understand what is what from such a markup. I'd rather use some more descriptive properties. Such as [location](http://schema.org/location) for physical address and [contactPoint](http://schema.org/contactPoint) for mailing address. 
So it should look like this

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">   
  <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
   <ul>
    <li>Office: <span itemprop="streetAddress">1234 Anywhere Street</span>
     <br/> <span itemprop="addressLocality">Denver</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion">CO</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">80000</span>
    </li>
   </ul>            
  </div>
  <div itemprop="contactPoint" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
   <ul>
    <li><span itemprop="contactType">Mailing: Post Office Box</span> <span itemprop="postOfficeBoxNumber">5555</span>
    <br/> <span itemprop="addressLocality">Denver</span>, <span itemprop="addressRegion">CO</span> <span itemprop="postalCode">80000</span>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div> 
  <div>
   <ul>
    <li>Phone: <span itemprop="telephone">555-555-5555</span></li>
    <li>Fax:  <span itemprop="faxNumber">555-555-5555</span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>      
</div>
```

Note that I've added *itemprop="contactType"* to specify explicitly type of contact point. It is simple text though (type of property) so you can use any description you like.

Another small remark that we can use schema.org/PostalAddress for contactPoint since it is child of http://schema.org/ContactPoint type.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and information. I was afraid of no one understanding but you helped solve the issue. Thank You!

Comment: Happy to help! Don't hesitate to accept answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: I always do => Sometimes I don't accept right away to give time for others to answer. Thanks.